# Tools to view/diagram function-call hierarchies for C or C++ source files in OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos, diagram

Are there any good source-code analyses tools for OSX. I am particularly interested in tools that are capable of diagramming function-call hierarchies for C and C++ source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might take a look at [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

Answer (score 2):

[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can do this and a lot more.